# blasting a refseq protein does not show the protein in the result set

Tags: blast, refseq

Can anyone explain me, why I don't find a specific protein with a blast that was took before from the NCBI refseq database?

Specifically, I was trying to blast the protein with the accession number "NP_420767" and its sequence, respectively, however that protein does not show up in the results. It not only happens when the standard options are chosen, but also, when "Reference proteins (refseq_protein)" as database in the blast options is selected.

I am really puzzled by that.. Shouldn't blast show the initial refseq entry in the results list as it is part of the refseq database and has the same sequence?

Comment: Relevant: [Duplicate long hits from PSI-BLAST](//bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/831)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NP_420767 is represented by the non-redundant refSeq protein WP_010919826, which has the same amino acid sequence. This is not very clearly annotated, but if you scroll down to the sequence in the GenPept entry for NP_420767, you'll see the following:

```
CONTIG      join(WP_010919826.1:1..799)
```

See [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/refseq/about/nonredundantproteins) for more info.

Comment: Ah, I understand.. And in the list after clicking on "identical proteins" on the "WP_010919826.1" site, "NP_420767" gets listed.